# Ruby - can't find cause for ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class Segment and I'm calling `segment.build`:

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates :filters, presence: true

  def build
    segment_builder = BuildSegment.new(self)
    segment_builder.call
  end
end
```

This is how BuildSegment looks:

```
class BuildSegment

  def initialize(segment)
    @segment = segment
  end

  def call
    users_to_add = users_meeting_requirements_for(@segment)

    add_users(@segment, users_to_add)
    remove_users(@segment, users_to_add)
  end

  private

  def remove_users(segment, users_to_add)
    segment.users.where.not(id: users_to_add.uniq).delete_all
  end

  def add_users(segment, users_to_add)
    segment.users << users_to_add.uniq
  end

  def users_meeting_requirements_for(segment)
    users = Array.new

    segment.filters.each do |filter|
      users << users_passing_filter(filter)
    end

    users.flatten.uniq
  end
```

This line: `users_to_add = users_meeting_requirements_for(@segment)`
gives me:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
from /Users/patryk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:23:in `initialize'
```

Why? `users_meeting_requirements_for` requires only one argument which I provide. I tried different combinations of instance and method variables called from inside of `users_meeting_requirements_for`, but nothing really changes.

I'm lost here.

Comment: deeper stack trace please this seems to have something to do with how you built a relationship and nothing to do with the code you are showing.

Comment: Just to make it clear :  The ArgumentError happens inside users_meeting_requirements_for, but the method call itself isn't the problem. This seems to be an ActiveRecord Relation problem, and you don't show any information related to Rails.

Comment: That's everything returned in console after calling Segment.last.build:

`Segment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "segments".* FROM "segments"  ORDER BY "segments"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
from /Users/patryk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:23:in `initialize'


Segment is a model, while BuildSegment is in app/services/build_segment.rb

I updated original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was hidden deeper than I previously thought. Argument error was inside another method called by `users_meeting_requirements_for`

I found it by commenting out line by line until I have reached the troublesome line.